# Disabled custom UIButton shows different image in different places

Tags: ios, image, uibutton

I have some custom UIButtons that show up in different places, but use the same image. When disabled, they appear different from each other, even though all the settings are identical.
One place the button is used is in a table view cell, the other is just as part of a nib layout. Any clue why these look so different?

Enabled in table view: [image: Enabled in table view]

Disabled in table view: [image: Disabled in table view]

Disabled in nib: [image: Disabled in nib]

Answer (score 3):

By default a button will apply a ghosting effect when it is disabled. You can turn off this behaviour by setting the `adjustsImageWhenDisabled` property to NO. This is also available in Interface Builder.

Comment: I've tried changing that setting on both sets of buttons with no effect. Plus, that doesn't explain why they would look so different.

Comment: I take that back - setting that to NO does have an effect on the buttons that are in the table view cells. They are no longer dimmed. But I'm good with the way they're dimmed.

Comment: OK, I must have misunderstood what the problem is. So the problem is that they appear gray in the nib?

Comment: No, they looked fine when viewing the nib file in the editor. But when I ran the app, they looked weird when disabled. The problem was code in the view controller's superclass was setting a different image for the disabled control state. So it was my own code that was the problem, as seems to be the usual case.

Answer (score 0):

Code in the view controller superclass was setting an image for disabled state, so of course it looked different.

Sorry for the noise.